# How to remove server/software information from apache http client response

Tags: java, xampp, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I wrote below sample program to check response of http

```
    public class CloseableHttpClientExmpl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CloseableHttpClient client =HttpClients.custom().disableContentCompression().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/index.php");
        CloseableHttpResponse response=null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output/response is like below

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2019 12:48:38 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8, X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8, Content-Length: 79, Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99, Connection: Keep-Alive, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 79,Chunked: false]}}
```

Now I want to know that How can I remove software informations like below from this response

```
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8, X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Server details mention below are sent by the server i.e. localhost in your case.

```
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8, X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8
```

You can disable 'Server' details sent as a part of the response in your server configuration. For windows server, using https://www.saotn.org/remove-iis-server-version-http-response-header/

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same through programming?

Comment: @ManojKumarDhakad Those values are headers in the response - they're not in the body of the response. As sauumum said, to stop the server sending them you need to change the configuration on the server. If on the client side - in your code - you are not interested in those values then just ignore the headers part of the response and look at the body.